# Keras Conv1D failing when kernel_size greater than 1

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am trying to build a simple CNN LSTM model for time series prediction and i am having some trouble with Conv1D layer. My input shape is `(100,12)` and when set `kernel_size` to anything other than 1, it fails and outputs

`Process finished with exit code -1073741818 (0xC0000006)`.

Code that is failing:

```
model.add(
    Conv1D(
        12,
        2,
        activation='tanh',
        padding='same',
        input_shape=(np.shape(self.x_train)[1], np.shape(self.x_train)[2])
    )
)
```

Comment: Please provide more details like x_train shape, sample data. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your post.